# GHC type error doesn't make sense to me

Tags: haskell, ghc

so i was playing around with Extensible effects trying to reimplement some of the fundamental types and functions when i got this type error :

```
home/kadhem/projects/Haskell/stackWorkingAgain/app/Implementation_error.hs:24:96: error:
    * Couldn't match type `x1' with `x'
      `x1' is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          Impure :: forall (r :: [* -> *]) a x.
                    Union r x -> (x -> Eff r a) -> Eff r a,
        in an equation for `createInterpreter'
        at /home/kadhem/projects/Haskell/stackWorkingAgain/app/Implementation_error.hs:22:59-68
      `x' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          createInterpreter :: forall a (r :: [* -> *]) b (f :: * -> *) x.
                               (a -> Eff r b)
                               -> (f x -> (x -> Eff (f : r) a) -> Eff (f : r) a)
                               -> (Eff r b -> Eff r b)
                               -> Eff (f : r) a
                               -> Eff r b
        at /home/kadhem/projects/Haskell/stackWorkingAgain/app/Implementation_error.hs:(15,1)-(18,47)
      Expected type: f x
        Actual type: f x1
    * In the first argument of `runContinuation', namely
        `f_is_theTarget'
```

i don't understand how is x1 bound by the constructor Impure.

here is the full code :

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTSyntax #-}
{-# LANGUAGE  DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE  FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}


module Implemntation where

import Data.OpenUnion (Union , decomp)


data Eff r a where 
   Pure :: a -> Eff r a
   Impure ::  Union r x -> (x -> Eff r a) -> Eff r a

createInterpreter :: (a -> Eff r b)
                  -> (f x -> (x -> Eff (f ': r) a) -> Eff (f ': r) a)
                  -> (Eff r b -> Eff r b) 
                  -> Eff (f ': r) a -> Eff r b


createInterpreter handlePure runContinuation applyEffect (Pure a) = 
      handlePure a
createInterpreter handlePure runContinuation applyEffect (Impure f k) 
      = case decomp f of
Right f_is_theTarget
     -> applyEffect $ createInterpreter handlePure runContinuation 
           applyEffect (runContinuation f_is_theTarget k)
Left f_is_notTheTarget
     -> Impure f_is_notTheTarget $ createInterpreter handlePure 
           runContinuation applyEffect  . k
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these two facts:

Fact 1: whoever calls `Impure` gets to choose the type of `x` in its type:

```
Impure ::  Union r x -> (x -> Eff r a) -> Eff r a
```

Note that such `x` does not end up in `Eff r a`, making the type an "existential" one.

Fact 2: whoever calls `createInterpreter` gets to choose the value of `x` in its type

```
createInterpreter :: (a -> Eff r b)
                  -> (f x -> (x -> Eff (f ': r) a) -> Eff (f ': r) a)
                  -> (Eff r b -> Eff r b) 
                  -> Eff (f ': r) a -> Eff r b
```

Note that this choice is *independent* from the first choice!

So, both these facts imply that when we call

```
createInterpreter handlePure runContinuation applyEffect (Impure f k)
```

we can pass a `runContinuation` function for a type `x` and pass `Impure` using a distinct type `x` (say, `x1`). Since you are trying to mix these types, the compiler complains that they do not have to be the same.

You might want the following type instead

```
createInterpreter :: (a -> Eff r b)
                  -> (forall x. f x -> (x -> Eff (f ': r) a) -> Eff (f ': r) a)
                  -> (Eff r b -> Eff r b) 
                  -> Eff (f ': r) a -> Eff r b
```

This will force you later on to pass a *polymorphic* `runContinuation` function, which works on any choice of `x` which might be found "inside" `Impure`.

---

Your example is quite complex, but to understand the issue you can also consider this similar case:

```
data SomeList where
   SL :: [x] -> SomeList

sumIntList :: [Int] -> Int
sumIntList = sum

workWithSL :: ([x] -> Int) -> SomeList -> Int
workWithSL f (SL list) = f list

test :: Int
test = workWithSL sumIntList (SL [True, False])
```

Here, we choose `x = Bool` when calling `SL`, but we choose `x = Int` when calling `workWithSL` (since we pass `sumIntList`). There is nothing wrong with such calls, since the types perfectly check out. The real issue is inside `workWithSL` which can not apply `f` to `list`, since the `list` may be of type `[x1]` instead of `[x]`.